# C# How to coordinate read and write threads while reconnecting NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networkstream

I have a thread writing requests to NetworkStream. Another thread is reading responses from this stream.

I want to make it fault tolerant. In case of network failure, I want NetworkStream to be disposed replaced by a brand new one.

I made the two threads handle IO/Socket exceptions. Each of them will try to re-establish the connection. I'm struggling to coordinate these two threads. I had to place lock sections making the code rather complicated and error-prone.

Is there a recommended way to implement this? Perhaps using a single thread but making Read or Write async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easiest to have a single thread that handles coordination and writing and then handle reading using async. By including a `CancellationTokenSource` in an `AsyncState` object the reader code can signal the sending thread to restart the connection, when the receiver encounters an error (calling `EndRead` or if the stream completes). The coordination/writer sits in a loop that creates the connection and then loops consuming a `BlockingCollection<T>` of items to send. By using `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(token)` the sender can be cancelled when the reader encounters an error.

```
    private class AsyncState
    {
        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        public NetworkStream NetworkStream { get; set; }
        public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
    }
```

Once you've created the connection you can start the async reading process (which keeps calling itself as long as everything is working). Passing the buffer, the stream and the `CancellationTokenSource` in the state object:

```
var buffer = new byte[1];
stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 1, Callback,
   new AsyncState
   {
       Buffer = buffer,
       NetworkStream = stream,
       CancellationTokenSource = cts2
   });
```

After that you start reading from your output queue and writing to the stream until cancelled or a failure happens:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII, 80, true))
{
    foreach (var item in this.sendQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
    {
       ...
```

... and in the Callback you can check for failures and, if necessary, hit the CancellationTokenSource to signal the writer thread to restart the connection.

```
private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  var state = (AsyncState)ar.AsyncState;

  if (ar.IsCompleted)
  {
    try
    {
        int bytesRead = state.NetworkStream.EndRead(ar);
        LogState("Post read ", state.NetworkStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Warn("Exception during EndRead", ex);
        state.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        return;
    }

    // Deal with the character received
    char c = (char)state.Buffer[0];

    if (c < 0)
    {
        Log.Warn("c < 0, stream closing");
        state.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        return;
    }

    ... deal with the character here, building up a buffer and
    ... handing it out to the application when completed
    ... perhaps using Rx Subject<T> to make it easy to subscribe

    ... and finally ask for the next byte with the same Callback

    // Launch the next reader
    var buffer2 = new byte[1];
    var state2 = state.WithNewBuffer(buffer2);
    state.NetworkStream.BeginRead(buffer2, 0, 1, Callback, state2);
```

Comment: That's the line I'd like to explore. I failed to picture the code for my use case though. I need to read two byte header which contains the length of the body and then read the body. How do I do that? I though of having ReadHeader which calls BeingRead with ReadBody but sounds like I need to read the rest of the body synchronously in ReadBody method. Also, how should I use CancellationTokenSource?

Comment: I added code to show how to handle reading one byte at a time and how the cancellation token is passed in and used to signal the writer thread when a read failure occurs. You could start by reading two bytes for the initial async read and then read the remainder in a single call.

Comment: Great. Do I really need state2? Why can't I reuse state?

Comment: Yes, could probably reuse state - I tend towards immutable data structures out of habit.